# APNS certificates: Changing servers - new IP Address but same domain

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm about to change VPS providers for the server which keeps my APNS push notifications. The domain name will remain the same but the IP address is changing.

Can I just copy my APNS certificates from the old server to new server or do I have to recreate them?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to regenerate APNS certificates until the certificate has not expired.

Certificates works on all serveurs, and are not generated for a server in particulary.